# Django Extra Views, CreateWithInlinesView - how to get InlineFormSet pass to _form.html?

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

How do I get `InlineFormSet` to show in my `building_form.html`?

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from extra_views import InlineFormSet, CreateWithInlinesView

from buildings.models import Building, Gallery
from .forms import BuildingForm

class GalleryInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Gallery
    fields = ['image', 'caption']

class BuildingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Building
    form_class = BuildingForm
    inlines = [GalleryInline, ]
    template_name = 'cms/building_form.html'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.forms import OSMWidget, ModelForm

from buildings.models import Building


class BuildingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'point': OSMWidget(
                attrs={
                    'map_width': 600,
                    'map_height': 600,
                    'template_name': 'gis/openlayers-osm.html',
                    'default_lat': 56,
                    'default_lon': 10,
                    'default_zoom': 7,
                }
            )
        }

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.css',
                'gis/css/ol3.css',
            )
        }
        js = (
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.20.1/ol.js',
            'gis/js/OLMapWidget.js',
        )
```

**building_form.html**

```
{% block content %}

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599809/using-a-django-filefield-in-an-inline-formset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492374/how-to-render-formset-in-template-django-and-create-vertical-table